# OR (|) doesn't work in notepad++ regexp search

Tags: regex, search, notepad++

I tried to search for `SQL` statements + some metadata in my logs using following search query:

```
(\d+?\s+?INSERT) | (\[\d+?\]\{\d+?\}\s+?SELECT)
```

but it finds only 1st part. If I put 2nd brackets in the first position - it finds it, but not the other one.

Comment: Do you have those spaces there around the `|` in your search? That might be your problem...

Comment: Could you show some lines from the log?

Comment: that was it, dummy mistake with spaces. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

you have a space between the two clause - that will be required to match and it won't if SELECT is at the beginning of a line